# Why won't my jQuery UI dialog work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Why won't my jQuery UI dialog work?

It works if I put the div on the page in the html but I want to rather dynamically insert it as below  then remove it with a click event.

```
var d = $("<div id='my' >any text</div>");

d.dialog({

     modal: true

});
```

Later I want to close it in another event with

```
$('td').click(function(){

   $("#my").dialog("close");

)};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the element, but don't seem to add it to the DOM? If you use the [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) method, you can add it to the DOM, prior to calling the `.dialog()` method.

Try something like this instead

```
$("<div id='my'>any text</div>").appendTo("body");
```

Comment: @Hello-World You wouldn't need to add it to a variable first. You could use chaining and just do this `$("<div id='my'>any text</div>").appendTo("body").dialog({ modal: true });` in a single line if you want.

Comment: does that meant that when it closes I must remove it to?

Comment: $().dialog already adds it to the dom if it's not there(at least as of 1.7.2)

Comment: @LiviuT. Didn't know that, thanks for the tip! Maybe OP is using an earlier version, since appending it seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson I think this a general lesson about jQuery: always include the version number ;)

Comment: I am using 1.7.2  and it looks like I have to also remove the div or it will keep adding it -- thanks everyone for the help